# Java replace all invalid character for regex

Tags: java, regex

My String is huge and it will keep changing as I read each String in a loop. It can contain any characters like " , / , \ . $ ,? , [ , & , . , ' , ) , % , ^ , + , * etc. I would like to escape all such characters that might cause a regex to fail on this string in Java. Javascript has something like this in one of the posts which goes like this-

```
return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
```

Is there something similar for Java? I'm not sure what should be the character set to escape. Would something like str.replaceAll("[^\u0000-\u00ff]+", " ") do that? (But I'm losing data here if I'm replacing ALL of them with a space, which I want to avoid)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
String myEscapedString = Pattern.quote(myRawString);
```